# Android post to rest webservice - with localhost glassfish

Tags: java, android, rest, post, glassfish

I have an android application and I need to enable the user to login. 
I have the login button and when the button is pressed by the user I call to an asyncTask to post the user data to the rest service. I'm able to call the method but when I debug the server side I see that the parameters are null, even though it sends as json object to the server.

**Android Client Code:**

```
class LoginByEmail extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String url = strings[0];
        String respStr = "";
        String userEmail    = strings[1];
        String userPassword = strings[2];

        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

        try{

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF8");

            data.put("email",userEmail);
            data.put("password",userPassword);


            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data.toString());
            post.setEntity(se);

            response = client.execute(post);
            respStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        }catch (Exception e){
                respStr = e.getMessage().toString();
        }
        return respStr;
    }
}
```

**Server Side Code**

```
 @Path("/emailLogin")
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public String emailLogin(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password)
 {
     String user = sm.loginByEmail(email,password);
     return user;
 }
```

I'm using glassfish as my webhost and deploy to it my rest webservice, the emailLogin function is from the rest webservice.

I don't understand why the email and password parameters are transferred as null.

**Note:** the userEmail and userPassword variables are not null, they gets their value properly

Any Idea?

Edit: variables values: [image]

Comment: can you log/print/etc the json object client side, just to confirm that the values aren't null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nameValuePairs instead of JSONOBject, this should work:

```
List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",userEmail));
data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",userPassword));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
```

EDIT:

I recommend you using this project as a Library.

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It makes you easy deal with apis, control network problems etc.

You can find a sample of use there.

You only have to:

Build your URL
Tell the component to execute in POST mode
Build your JSON

Good luck!

Comment: thanks I'll try it. do you why jsonObject is not working? because it still wanted to be transferred as json. +1 because it works :)

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a link to a component that I've developed. You can send JSONObjects with it, and make GET/PUT/POST requests, control your internet connection in order to show a toast or do anything when the device has no connection etc. It's very easy to use. Please, mark the answer as there correct if it really is!! :)